# Text formatting for a string

Tags: apache-flex

Can I set the font size for string?                                                          I want to do text formatting for string, Is it possible in flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TextField/UITextField to display formatted text. In both classes you have two options:

1. You can use [setTextFormat()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getTextFormat%28%29) method to format text
2. You can use htmlText property to display HTML text. These classes don't support all HTML tags. Supported HTML tags are listed [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText).

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is change the font, you can use the [StyleableTextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/StyleableTextField.html) class or the [Label](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html) and set the .  She can set the fontSize style of either class to globally change the font size.

Answer (score 0):

No,

you need to set the font size of label or any text other Text control that you use to show string value.

```
var str:String = 'This is sample text';

//set in any method
lbl.text = str;
lbl.setStyle('fontSize', 20);
```

enjoy.